# How to remove comments when server returns a JSP page?

Tags: regex, jsp, tomcat, ant

Which class of tomcat is responsible for converting .jsp file to .class file? I want to see the source code written for the conversion. My aim is to check the logic how scriptlet comments are eliminated and based on that I'll write my own code that will remove HTML comments as well (I've not decided how will I implement it).

I am sure source code should be available as it's open source.

Or is it possible to implement some kind of filter so the each time server returns a JSP page it removes the comments. I can replace all HTML comments into Scriptlet comments. But I want to ensure, if someone use html comments in future, it is not displayed. It's basically for security.

**[Added]**

As per the suggestion given by JB Nizet, we will be modifying build.xml file to remove comments. I have come up with this to remove HTML comments -

```
<target name="-trim.html.comments">
    <echo message="Inside trim html comments" /> 
    <fileset id="html.fileset" dir="${build.dir}" includes="**/*.jsp, **/*.html" />
        <!-- HTML Comments -->
    <replaceregexp replace="" flags="g" match="\&lt;![ \r\n\t]*(--([^\-]|[\r\n]|-[^\-])*--[ \r\n\t]*)\&gt;">
    <fileset refid="html.fileset"/>
        </replaceregexp>
</target>
```

However, I am not sure how to remove comments that starts with // or /* */. Any suggestion how can I do so? I have searched over internet but didn't get a clue.

We are using ant script for build.

**[Added]**

To remove single line comment that starts with // I am using below regex. But somehow it's not working. Can anyone please help me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
<replaceregexp flags="gs" match="?:^\s*\/\/(?:.*)$" replace="">
```

Comment: Why don't you simply add a task in your build process that makes sure that no JSP contains `<!--`? That would be extremely simple to implement, it would educate your developers, it would cost nothing at runtime, and it wouldn't tie your solution to any specific tomcat implementation.

Comment: Are you using a web server like Apache?  Many of them have minification modules that would do the job, like Apache's [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html).

Comment: Yes. I we are using apache.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing it in Tomcat, use Apache directly.  It supports modules which do exactly what you need.  [mod pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module) is probably closest to what you want; [mod deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) may be configurable to do the same thing, though it also compresses the data, which might be overkill.

As a nice side-effect, this allows you to leave your handy comments in and they'll be served to your internal users (developers) who use port 8080, while those using port 80 will see only the minified product.